# Enable Windows Authentication with Active Directory Group for Single page HTML site

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, iis-10

I have a single page HTML site which has HTML pages lying in virtual directory. I want to authenticate application using window authentication(Active Directory Group) in IIS 10.0.
My problem its not happening, all users can access the site. I have tried following code and configuration in my web.config file, the same code works with other asp.net site without problem yet it does not work with single page html code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>    
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="MY_DOMAIN\ActiveDirectoryGroupName" />
            <deny users="*" />           
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

[image]

I understand that HTML is client side scripting language yet Is there any way to enable window authentication(Active Directory Group) in single page HTML site without complicating solution.
If not what could be easiest way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You used the wrong authorization rules. The right ones are https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authorization/add

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use the below web.conifg file code to restrict all other users and allow domain users with windows authentication.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
                <add accessType="Allow" roles="MY_DOMAIN\test" />
                <add accessType="Deny" users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and make sure you enable windows authentication at your site level.

[image]

Comment: I have applied these settings and those are prompting for user name and password for the users who are not part of the group but if they entered correct username/password. They are allow to access the site.

Comment: @BhaskarSingh make sure you enabled iis URL authorization feature. check you set this link in your authorization  `<remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />` , clear browser history and try again to access the site.

Comment: No, it did not worked. Finally I have converted my HTML page to ASPX page and now all security are working.

Comment: @BhaskarSingh if your issue is resolved then post the helpful suggestion and mark it as an answer it will help other people who face a similar issues.

Comment: I have converted html pages in aspx pages and hosted them with the settings which were provided in scree shot earlier. It look like that HTML files does not honor those settings.